# what happened if the deployed war does not exist on its path?

Tags: war

I have deployed a war on the Weblogic server. I would like to know if that war file happens to be deleted/removed from its physical location on the server from where it was deployed, what will be the impact of this?

Regards,

Dushyant

Answer (score 0):

When you are deploying the war file, there is a page of optional settings, one of which is "Source Availability".

If you choose "Use the defaults defined by the deployment's targets" or "Copy this application onto every target for me" you don't need to worry about the original war file being deleted as it has already been copied to each server. The deployment uses staged mode for all the managed servers and non-staged mode for the Admin server.

If you choose "Make the deployment accessible from the following location" and then delete that war/directory your application will no longer continue to work. This is non-staged mode.